# detailCalloutAccessoryView constraints in MKAnnotationView

Tags: ios, constraints, mapkit, mkannotationview

i have some problems sizing a detailCalloutAccessoryView that i added programmatically.

Here's the code for the view

```
HCSStarRatingView *annotationRating = [[HCSStarRatingView alloc] init];
annotationView.detailCalloutAccessoryView = annotationRating;
```

I tried to init the view with a initWithFrame but somehow that didn't work and i ended up with this.

[image: First Try]

I then discovered that i have to add NSLayoutConstraint programmatically to size the view correctly, so i added this code for constraints.

```
NSLayoutConstraint *width = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:annotationRating attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:80];
NSLayoutConstraint *height = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:annotationRating attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:45];
[annotationRating addConstraint:width];
[annotationRating addConstraint:height];
```

And the view now looks like this

[image: Getting closer]

Now i want to get rid of the white space around it. I think i have to add a top and bottom constraint but i don't know how to do it because I don't know what items i have to relate to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The excess whitespace is a function of the `height` that you've chosen. Your image is roughly 5 times as wide as it is tall, but you've asked to render it in a box that 80 x 45 pts (i.e. a view whose height is over half the width, rather than one fifth). If you pick the dimensions of the image view to match (adjusting for scale) the size of the image, you get something more like:

[image]

As you can see, with judicious selection of the width and height, there will be less whitespace than in your example. Note, there is some inherent whitespace between the detail accessory view that you cannot control, but by making sure you set the width and height correctly, you can reduce it to these minimal values.